# Turn off automatic size adjustment of \left and \right brackets

Tags: math-mode, brackets

I have used different left/right brackets (`\left(`, `\left[`, `\left\{` etc.) in a document numerous time and realised only now (due to changes) that the automatic size adjustment that comes with these brackets/braces does not fit well and that I mostly want the “normal” size for all instead.

Is there a way to turn off this automatic size adjustment, such that for each brace the same (normal) size is used? I know I should, given my change of mind, probably replace each `\left(` by a plain `(`, but I am hoping for a quick (though possibly dirty) solution.

Comment: You can try:  

`\let\saveleft\left \let\saveright\right `

`\def\left#1{#1} \def\right#1{#1}`, of course a dirty solution :-).

Of course you can use `\saveleft` and `\saveright` if you want original `\left` and `\right`.

Comment: No, sorry. You can't disable `\left` and `\right` in general: you won't be able to use `\big`, `\Big` and friends, which you probably *do* want to use.

Comment: @egreg thanks for pointing that out - indeed an unfortunate side-effect. It seems there is no solution that maintains the sizes of `\big` and the like?

Comment: @Bernd No, unless you modify the definitions of `\big` and friends to use the original `\left` and `\right`. Search and replace, it's easier.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I **don't** recommend this really!

`\left` is actually a `TeX` command and has one argument being the delimiter. In this case, the delimiter should be typeset only,so the effect of `\left` is to be gobbled. (The same is for `\right...`)

As campa noted in his comment: `\left...` and `\right...` are important commands in `amsmath` and changing their definitions will not break for example `matrix` etc. resulting in an compilation error but it will break their visual appareance.

I've stored `\left...` and `\right...` for the `pmatrix` environment for example to show how to preserve the usual behaviour there!

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\let\origleft\left
\let\origright\right

% Save it for the pmatrix environment, for example
\xpatchcmd{\pmatrix}{\left(}{\origleft(}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\endpmatrix}{\right)}{\origright)}{}{}




\begin{document}

Before

$\left(\left(a+b\right)^2\right)$

$\left[\left(a+b\right)^2\right]$

$\left\{\left(a+b\right)^2\right\}$

$\begin{pmatrix}
  a & b \\
  c & d \\
\end{pmatrix}$


Now redefining them:

\renewcommand{\left}[1]{%
#1
}
\renewcommand{\right}[1]{%
#1%
}

After:

$\left(\left(a+b\right)^2\right)$

$\left[\left(a+b\right)^2\right]$

$\left\{\left(a+b\right)^2\right\}$

$\begin{pmatrix}
  a & b \\
  c & d \\
\end{pmatrix}$



\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @campa: Yes, thanks, I was about to provide some examples to show why it's not good actually!

Comment: @ChristianHupfer What about `\big`, etc.? `\big: macro:#1->{\hbox {$\left #1\vbox to8.5\p@ {}\right .\n@space $}}`.

Comment: @HenriMenke: Right, but the question was about `\left,..` etc.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer But if you let `\left` to `\relax` then not only all *automatic* size adjustments by *explicit* `\left` are disabled, but also all *manual* size adjustments by *implicit* `\left`, cf. the definition of `\big`.