# Braket size problem

Tags: size, braket

I have a braket term in an equation. The bra size is bigger than the ket size due to a primed item in the bra part. I know that \big function can make ket size bigger and it can match the height but i want to make the bra size smaller:

```
\documentclass[phys]    
\begin{document}
    \begin{equation}
      \bra{\vec{q'}}\ket{\vec{q}}
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Do you have any suggestions ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: [Welcome to TEX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) would be helpful here. In particular: what exactly are you using to make bras and kets? The answer may depend on that.

Comment: there are many definitions for brakes notation that will ensure teh sizes match,. what definition are you using for bra and ket here? (please always make your example complete, so people can run it)

Comment: I editted my question, i think it makes more sense now, thanks !

Comment: @user175924 What is `\documentclass[phys] `? If possible, try to give an example with `\documentclass{article}`. `phys` is not known to me, where do you have it from? And the []-notation looks wrong. Should be {}

Comment: Everything is fine in \documentclass{article}. I have to use this one because of some reasons. I think all you can do is to suggest any adjustment function that you know and I will try them. Thank you so much !

Comment: @heater-- thank you but as barbara beeton said, these are not ordinary brackets, it is essentially the command: \langle \vert \rangle (I have tried this also, didn't work.)

Comment: i've just tested this using `\documentclass{article} \usepackage{braket}` and the size of the `\bra` on the left side is the same size as the angle bracket on the right.  so you must have something more complicated that we aren't seeing.  (i do find it unpleasant that the arrow on the right is bumping into the closing angle bracket.)

Comment: as rude solution: `\ket{\vec{q\vphantom{'}}`, maybe it can help in time of searching for better solution :-)

Comment: @Zarko -- but that would make the prime invisible.  not what's wanted.  `\smash` would be more appropriate.

Comment: I guess its because of the documentclass that i'm using, so let me ask you this: Is there any way to stop the automatic size adjustment of the bracket ? (Yeah it is annoying but more reasonable than what i have :) )

Comment: @Zarko-- Thank you but what I want to do is make the left one smaller, not to make the right one bigger.

Comment: Is `\braket` defined in this class by any chance? `\braket{\vec{q'}|\vec{q}}` would, I think, have the desired effect if the braket package were being used.

Comment: (+1) for this phrase in the description: "The bra size is bigger than the ket size due to a primed item in the bra part.". Now I know how to name my macros :))

Comment: @alwaysask-- :)) If I redefine a bracket, do you think it will solve the problem ?

Comment: After a long search, I have found the solution to my problem. \usepackage{xpatch} is the solution for my problem. However, I could not apply since it necessitates new definitions. Is there anyone experienced with this package ? Here is the link that explains the way to execute it: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/278470/turn-off-automatic-size-adjustment-of-left-and-right-brackets

Answer (score 6):

this is not an answer, but a demonstration of possibilities.

the code shown in the question doesn't exhibit the described result, namely
that the left angle bracket is larger than the right one.

**edit:**
since the request was for a *smaller* set of brakets, i've added examples showing
that the shapes used around the *q* are the smallest *default* size.  to get
smaller ones, one has to go to ridiculous lengths, explicitly specifying a
different (and inappropriate) size.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
 \begin{equation*}
   \bra{\vec{q'}}\ket{\vec{q}} \quad
   \bra{\vec{a'}}\ket{\vec{a}} \quad
   \bra{a'}\ket{a} \quad
   {\scriptstyle \bra{{\textstyle{a'}}}\ket{\textstyle{a}}}
 \end{equation*}

 \begin{equation*}
   \bra{\vec{q}\,\smash{'}}\ket{\vec{q}\,} \quad
   \bra{\vec{a}\,\smash{'}}\ket{\vec{a}\,}
 \end{equation*}

 \begin{equation*}
   \bra{\vphantom{a}\smash{\vec{q'}}}\ket{\vec{q}\,} \quad
   \bra{\smash{\vec{a'}}}\ket{\vec{a}\,}
 \end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

note that the coding here isn't good style -- never use multiple adjacent `equation` environments.  and i've also taken liberties with spacing,
since it's not really clear what is wanted.

**edit:**
it has come to my attention (by way of a comment on [Increase in bracket sizes due to power symbol](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/331036/579)) that the `physics` package also supports the `\bra` `\ket` notation, and according to `texdoc physics` you can apply a `*` to suppress automatic sizing (see page 6).

Comment: Thank you so much, but as I said, I want to make my bracket size smaller. at least now I know how to make the smaller ones bigger and how to arrange the vector sign :))

Comment: Hello again ! I still have this issue, I was wondering if it is possible to produce the first example as one complete bracket instead of two separate items, such as

        \bra{\vec{q^{\prime}}}\hat{H}\ket{\vec{q}})

Comment: @user175924 -- i'm afraid i don't understand your question.  the code you show produces the bra-ket parts at the (same) expected size, with the embellished *H* between them.  it's no different from your original question.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not produce the bracket at the same size in my tex. Because of the prime , bra size is bigger than ket size.

Comment: @user175924 -- you are using `\documentclass{phys}`.  we don't know what that is, or where to get it.  unless we have that information, we aren't able to help any more than we already have.

Comment: It is a custom documentclass of the template which I have to use. Thank you so much !! I think I will try to figure it out on my own.

Answer (score -1):

Suggest to try a simple

```
\bigl<\ve{q}^{\,\prime}\bigl|\ve{q}\,\bigr>\bigr.
```

in `article` document class.

Comment: @DaiBowen -- while `\ve` is certainly not defined everywhere, `\bigl` and `\bigr` are tex primitives, so if they're not recognized, the tex engine being used isn't conformant.