# Increase in bracket sizes due to power symbol

Tags: equations, brackets

I have the following tex code,

```
\begin{equation}
\ket{f_{\alpha}(\bm{r}+\bm{e}_{\alpha} \Delta t, t+\Delta t)} = 
\ket{f_{\alpha}(\bm{r},t)} -\bm{M}^{-1}\hat{\bm{S}}
(\ket{m_{\alpha}(\bm{r},t)}-\ket{m_{\alpha}^{(eq)}(\bm{r},t)}),
\end{equation}
```

which provides the following equation  [image: eqn]
The right-most `ket` operator is bigger due to the `^(eq)`. How to bring the `ket` brace to normal size?

Comment: Can you add the definition of `\ket`

Comment: It's part of the `physics` package. You can refer this answer: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/214731/44940

Comment: in this answer (actually, a non-answer), [Braket size problem](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/325290/579), one of the examples uses `\smash` to diminish the height of what's inside the brakets.  that's the approach i'd suggest.  if you find that useful, i'll produce a "tailored" solution for this particular example.

Comment: according to `texdoc physics` you can use `\ket*` to suppress automatic sizing (see page 8)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle -- thanks for mentioning the `physics` package.  i only knew about `braket`, and the features and support are different.  so what is done depends on which package is actually used.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Works perfectly. Post this as answer!

Comment: Just add the [`braket` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/braket) after loading [`physics`](http://ctan.org/pkg/physics).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to

```
texdoc physics
```

you can use `\ket*` to suppress automatic sizing (see page 6)

Comment: The joys of `\left` and `\right`